# Change start point of circle in Canvas?

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I found this code to type on an arc in a Canvas element. I've modified it basically to what I need, but I'm not sure how to change the "starting point" of it?

I've got a demo [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/demchak_alex/Vwd6n/3/)

Answer (score 0):

```
circle = {
    x: cnv.width / 2,  // x coordinate of center
    y: cnv.height / 2, // y coordinate of center
    r: 150,
    lw: 75
};
```

for example, giving as given below will plot it at the origin of the canvas

```
circle = {
    x: 0,  // x coordinate of center
    y: 0, // y coordinate of center
    r: 150,
    lw: 75
};
```